# Office.js fails to initialize in Word add-in with Angular

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js

I'm building an (JS based) add-in for Word and it seems that I'm somehow unable to properly load (or actually, initialize) the office.js library when using the add-in in Word, both online as well as the desktop clients. I cannot execute any functions related to the office.js.

I've done some debugging and I found out that the sample projects work just fine, based on that finding I removed Angular from my add-in and it works fine that way. I load the office.js in exactly the same way in both the projects with and without angular. Is there a known incompatibility between Angular and Office add-ins? I haven't been able to find anything on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a common error that I, and others, have come across several times when building angular apps in the context of an Office add-in. The office.js initialize function is there to  set-up the communication between the add-in frame and the Office host application. If the office.js does not respond to the host application within 5 seconds after loading the add-in, it will fail. In this case, what happens often is that the office.js is loaded after (or by) angular, by then the 5 seconds are gone. What you should do is bootstrap angular in your office initialize. A more elaborate explanation and a guide on how to do this can be found here: https://www.itunity.com/article/building-excel-2016-addin-angular-enhanced-officejs-2637